# An ER diagram for supermarket chain

Tags: entity-relationship

I am taking a database course. As homework, I was asked to design an ER diagram for a supermarket chain. The ones given to me were customer, branch, and product entities and attributes of these entities. What was asked of me was to create a design that would allow me to keep the following features in the database when the customer purchased a product:

1. Which customer bought the product (customer id),
2. Which product he bought (product id),
3. From which branch it purchased (branch id),
4. When he bought it.

So I wanted to put an order relationship between these three entities (product, customer, and branch) and I came up with something like this.

[image: ER diagram]

Note that in this diagram, order relationship uses cid, pid and bid as a foreign key.

But then I thought that the order relationship actually has nothing to do with the branch, so the order relationship should only be between the product and the customer. But when I drew it that way, I didn't know how to add the branch id to the order relationship because the branch entity is not linked to the order relationship. So do you think the branch entity should be linked to this relationship or should it be drawn in another way?
Thanks already for your help.

Note: Cardinality constraints were not paid attention to.

Answer (score 0):

Developing a Relational Database Model for simple grocery shop.

ABC groceries is a conventional grocery shop. In their grocery shop they supply lot of grocery items from different vendors on credit basis. Then these grocery items are sold to customers on cash basis. And the purchase payment is paid to vendors after one month credit period based on bulk purchases. This is the process happening in ABC groceries.

Assumption: It was assumed that all the item in this grocery shop is marked with bar codes.

Imagine that you are assigned with the task of developing an on-premises MIS. First develop an entity relationship diagram and then develop the relational database model for ABC groceries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).